# Redirecting ONLY error messages from compile message of java source code

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, io-redirection

I want to redirect only error messages from compile message to output stream(a file).

For example, `javac file.java 2> errorCollectingFile` would redirect error messages together with warnings,notes,etc; not just errors.

To disable warning messages, `-nowarn` flag can be used. I'm not aware of how to disable notes in message. Also, I've not encountered any type of message other than these 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way redirect only the error messages and not the warning messages.

As a general statement, redirection happens at the shell level, and the stream contents will depend entirely on what the program (in this case `javac`) decides to write to the "standard output" and "standard error" streams.

The `javac` command line syntax provides no way to say to send different kinds of messages to different streams or to different files.  (And I'm not aware of compilers for other languages that would do that either ...)  That means that redirection of the streams at the shell level won't solve your problem.

If you want a solution, then I think you are going to have to redirect all of the messages to a file and then write some scripting to filter the different kinds of messages to different places.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If one wants to use script to filter out messages other than errors, that script will be based on message printing syntax of a particular compiler. Right? Is there any other way?